# Is an Intel Core i3 fast enough for 1080p Flash video streaming?

Tags: laptop, video, cpu, streaming

I have an old 2010 laptop (HP Compaq Pressario CQ62 - with Core i3).
When I watch HD TV episodes on this laptop, the CPU consumption goes to 100% after about 5 minutes (no other programs running), the video starts lagging, and then I have to shut down my laptop.

I am planning to buy a new laptop and I'm wondering whether a Core i3 will be enough for watching 1080p HD Streaming videos over internet or not.

Comment: yes, it should be fine. your laptop going to 100 CPU usage is not normal, and you should address that issue before you decide to purchase another laptop if it's only because of this reason. Suggestion, try another browser, reinstall Flash.

Comment: If you lower the resolution does the performance get beter?

Comment: The current Core i3 will definitely be able to handle 1080p, and in a lot of case provide hardware acceleration (for Flash) which will use very little CPU resource.

Comment: I have a Dell Vostro 3500 myself with a first-gen Core i3 (380M I think) and the same resolution (1366x768), and I can play Full HD videos just fine

Comment: @teenup Which Windows version do you have?

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can watch it without problems as long as five minutes, it's not that it's the CPU that is too weak. If it was, you would notice that after just a few seconds.

The CPU usage doesn't normally build up over time, so it's likely that the main cause is that you are running out of some other resource, for example memory. You should check that you have the newest versions of the flash player and the graphics driver.

According to Adobe, the minimum requirement for watching HD video is an **Intel Core Duo 1.8GHz** or equivalent CPU:

[Flash Player Help / Poor video quality | Flash Player](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/poor-video-quality-flash-player.html)

The Core i3 processor is so much better and newer than the Core Duo that it's hard to find comparisons between them. The Core i3 is two CPU generations newer, so it's definitely well above the minimum requirements.

Comment: I didn't have latest flash player installed on the laptop. It worked at 5% CPU consumption after installing it.